# If I run a command with `sudo` is it still "invoked by an ordinary user"?

Tags: process, sudo, users, davfs2

Quote from manpage of `davfs2.conf` for `mount.davfs`:

> There  is  a system wide configuration file /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf and user configuration files  ~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf.  When  mount.davfs  is invoked  by root, only the system wide configuration file is read. When invoked by an ordinary user, the user configuration  file  is  read  in addition.

If I call `mount.davfs` with `sudo` like

```
sudo mount -t davfs ...
```

Will this still count as "invoked by an ordinary user" and therefore read my `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf`? Or does `sudo` make this call "invoked by root" and `~/.davfs2/davfs2.conf` will be ignored?

Comment: I would assume sudo is not "an ordinary user". If you test `sudo printenv`, you will see that `$HOME`, etc. are now from root, although other variables are still from the user. Can you just test it?

Comment: Isn't the point of `sudo` running any command as other user (default-ly root)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split hairs in order to answer your question:

- `sudo` is "invoked by an ordinary user" (you)
- `mount` is "invoked by root", since the default action of `sudo` is to invoke the subsequent command as the root user.

A quick test (assuming you have `sudo` privileges that let you run `id`) is:

`id`

followed by:

`sudo id`

In the former, you see your own user; in the latter, you see that `id` was invoked "as the root user".